# Imprimir desde servidor Glassfish

Tags: java, servidor, glassfish, impresión

Tengo un servidor Glassfish en donde genero y guardo un archivo zpl (para impresoras zebra) a través de una aplicación web estándar en la ruta por default /var/tmp.

El proceso de guardado lo hace correctamente, inmediatamente después de esto quiero mandarlo a imprimir en la máquina de donde están usando la aplicación web, pero por alguna razón no lo hace. Quisiera saber si tienen algunos tips para poder lograr esto.

Aquí mi código:

```
//Guardo el archivo
public void saveZplFile(String ID) {
    try {
        java.io.PrintWriter out = new java.io.PrintWriter(new java.io.FileWriter(new java.io.File(rutaServer)));
        out.print(this.zpl);
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("El archivo '" + ruta + "' no pudo se creado. Motivo:\n " + ex.toString());
    }
}

//Proceso de impresion
public int print (Graphics g, PageFormat f, int pageIndex)
{
    String almacena="";
    String rutaServer="/var/tmp/Zebra_1612017.zpl";


    if(pageIndex==0) {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(rutilla));
            String line;
            int valorIncrementa=100;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                  valorIncrementa = valorIncrementa+10;
                  g.drawString(line, 100,valorIncrementa);
                  System.out.println("imprimiendo> " + line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR DE IMPRESION " + e.toString());
        }
        return PAGE_EXISTS;
    } else
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
}
```

Este proceso funciona en mi local, pero al momento de pasarlo al servidor de test o producción no funciona.

Comment: Dices que necesitas llamar a una impresora pero viendo tu código no encuentro las sentencias apropiadas. Ahora, te recomendaría crear un programa de consola donde puedas mandar un documento a imprimir a la impresora que indicas. Si puedes lograr hacerlo andar desde allí, entonces podrá imprimir desde tu servidor. Considera que la impresión deberá realizarse desde el servidor y no desde el cliente. El cliente lo único que puede hacer es preparar la información que deberá armar el servidor para mandar a imprimir desde este.

Comment: Hola @LuiggiMendoza gracias por tus comentarios, las opciones que mencionas se me complicarian un poco, la otra que se me ocurre es una vez generado el archivo en servidor puedo hacer la descarga y sobre esa descarga hacer una vista previa del contenido del documento que tenga la opcion de mandar a imprimir ya sobre el lado del cliente.Saludos.

Comment: Creo que no entiendes. No es que esté dándote opciones, así es como funciona el desarrollo de lado del servidor. Si lo que quieres es que el cliente imprima el archivo, entonces lo más que puede hacer tu aplicación es, como dices, generar el archivo y ofrecerlo para descarga. Luego, quedará a opción del cliente si 1) acepta la descarga, 2) la descarga no falla, 3) abre lo que ha descargado, 4) lo manda a imprimir desde su equipo. La decisión es tuya.